# Custom data frame from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this nested dictionaires in python that i need to build a data frame from
any simple idea to get the custom dataframe output as the following ?

```
my_dict = {
            'A' :{
                'x' : 1,
                'y' : 2
            },
            'B' :{
                't' : 3,
                'r' : 4
            },
            'C' :{
                'i' : 5,
                'j' : 6
            }
        }
```

I need my output data frame to be something like this structure

```
column 1 | column 2 |column 3
A        | x        |1
A        | y        |2
B        | t        |3
B        | r        |4
C        | i        |5
C        | j        |6
```

Answer (score 3):

Use flatten dict comprehension for list of tuples and pass to `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k1, k2, v2) for k1, v1 in my_dict.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()],
                  columns=['column 1','column 2','column 3'])
print (df)
  column 1 column 2  column 3
0        A        x         1
1        A        y         2
2        B        t         3
3        B        r         4
4        C        i         5
5        C        j         6
```

Comment: how i didn't of that .... Thanks a lot